# How to use an if...else statement in R?

Tags: r, database, if-statement, dataframe, dataset

I'm trying to create a variable using an if-statement. I want to check whether variable "st" exists in the dataframes in the list of dataframes "dflist", and if it doesn't exist I want to create variable "st". I tried to do it like this(however, it doens't work):

```
                    #making list of dataframes, and reading them into r
    mylist = list.files(pattern="*.dta")
    dflist <- lapply(mylist, read.dta13)

# if "st" exists in every dataframe in dflist, return "yes", else if it doesn't exist in a particular dataframe, create variable "st" in those dataframes

if(exists(st, dflist)){
    "yes"
  } else{
    st <- c("total")
    dflist$st <- st
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and create a column in the 'data.frame' `if` 'st' is not there.

```
dflist1 <- lapply(dflist, function(x) if(!exists("st", x))
                      transform(x, st = "total") else x)
```

#### data

```
dflist <- list(data.frame(v1 = 1:5), data.frame(st = 1:6))
```